# Two Audio Synchronous Playback And Change CurrentTime

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio

I'm trying to make a simple C# WinForms app, based on NAudio, that allows me to play two perfectly synchronized audio files (two tracks with same duration played in unison: Basically, they should both start from the beginning at same time and end in the end together)

I also need to manipulate volume (individually, for each track) and playback position (one single control, like a button which, once clicked, makes the two tracks go forward 10 seconds, but always in unison) during playback

Everything seems to work fine, but when I programmatically change playback position, the two tracks get out of phase a little bit (with each new iteration, it gets worse)

Here the highlights of the code I am using:

```
// variables
AudioFileReader fr1, fr2;
WaveChannel32 ch1, ch2;
MixingWaveProvider32 mix;
WaveOut wo;

// button play click handler
private void ButtonPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fr1 = new AudioFileReader("track1.mp3");
    fr2 = new AudioFileReader("track2.mp3");

    ch1 = new WaveChannel32(fr1, 1.0f, 0f);
    ch2 = new WaveChannel32(fr2, 1.0f, 0f);

    ch1.CurrentTime = new TimeSpan(0L);
    ch2.CurrentTime = new TimeSpan(0L);

    mix = new();
    mix.AddInputStream(ch1);
    mix.AddInputStream(ch2);

    var wo = new();
    wo.Init(mix);
    wo.Play();
}

// one of two volume sliders volumeChanged handler
private void VolumeSlider1_VolumeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ch1.Volume = VolumeSlider1.Volume;
}

// skip 10 sec button click handler
private void ButtonSkip10Sec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wo.Stop();
    ch1.CurrentTime += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    ch2.CurrentTime += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    wo.Play();
}
```

Please, let me know if I need to provide more relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

You want to swap the button event to:

```html
// skip 10 sec button click handler
private void ButtonSkip10Sec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newTime = ch1.CurrentTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    
    if (newTime <= ch1.TotalTime)
    {
        ch1.CurrentTime = newTime;
        ch2.CurrentTime = newTime;
    }
}
```

It could be that stopping the audio then adjusting the CurrentTime, and then starting the audio again might be causing a small delay between the two audio files.

The code above adjusts the CurrentTime of each channel to the new time without stopping the audio. It also checks if the new time would be beyond the TotalTime of the audio, in which case it doesn't adjust the CurrentTime.

If it's not this then it could be something to do with NAudio and how it handles the streams, hopefully not though as that'd be much harder to sort out I expect.